# .getTime() Alternative without milliseconds

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use the Date().getTime() function without getting the time in milliseconds? If not is there a substitute for .getTime() which will only give me the precision in minutes?

Also I'm not sure how to just strip the milliseconds out of the date object.

```
var time = new Date().getTime()

Output: 1426515375925
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you want? `getTime` returns the ms since 1/1/1970, so there is no part that *isn't* milliseconds. Did you want to convert it to something else? If you want it in seconds, minutes, hours, or whatever, then it's just simple math. Please read the [docs for date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Comment: Is there a different function I can use that will give me only the minutes since 1/1/1970, I just dont want the number to be as precise.

Comment: @DomX23: Read the docs. No, there isn't. Because it's trivial to convert from milliseconds to minutes.

Comment: Look at the answer by @James Donelly , you have to use the result of `var time = new Date().getTime()` and make it less precise yourself.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simple arithmetic. If you want the value in seconds, divide the milliseconds result by 1000:

```
var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

You might want to call `Math.floor()` on that to remove any decimals though:

```
var seconds = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
```

> Is there a different function I can use that will give me only the minutes since 1/1/1970, I just dont want the number to be as precise.

Certainly, divide the seconds by 60, or divide the milliseconds by 60000:

```
var minutes = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 60000);
```

---

```
var milliseconds = 1426515375925,
    seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000),  // 1426515375
    minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / 60000); // 23775256
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case (date without miliseconds), I wanted miliseconds to always be zero, so it would be like:

hh:mm:ss:000

Here is how I achived it:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
// Make miliseconds = 0 (precision full seconds)
time -= time % 1000;
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone

Comment: This is useful for getting the full timestamp value with the miliseconds set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Here a quick way to remove the milisecont from the `getTime`

```
var milli = new Date().getTime()
var timeWithoutMilli = Math.floor(milli/1000);
```

That will return the number of seconds

Comment: But you'll lose any trailing zeros

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to remove the milliseconds:

```
Long date = new Date().getTime() / 1000 * 1000
```

**1582302824091**L becomes **1582302824000**L

**2020-02-21 17:33:44.091** becomes **2020-02-21 17:33:44.0**

Answer (score 1):

Date object of the current time:

```
var time = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the time is set to the number of miliseconds since the epoch. To get the number of seconds, simply divide that number by 1000, and round to get a whole number

```
Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
```

To get the number of minutes divide that number by 60

```
Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000/60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull each portion of the time you want and put in a formatted string, like

```
var time = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString().split(':').slice(0, 2).join(':')
```

Will return "hh:MM"